# Error when setting string parameter to native query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

We are using Hibernate in one of our projects and there we use native queries.
In one of the native queries the sql looks like: 
`AND LNG_ISO = :searchLang`.
Then I set the parameter like:

```
query.setParameter("searchLang", "deu");
```

But the result shows, that this parameter was not taken into account.
The query is correct, as replacing 
`AND LNG_ISO = :searchLang` with `AND LNG_ISO = 'deu'` returns the expected result.

What is wrong with my string parameter?
Maybe I have to wrap the value in single quotation marks, but I did not find a way how to do it.

Comment: add the full code that creates and invokes the query

Comment: Using JPA API, or something else?

Comment: Yes, using JPA API

Answer (score 0):

In general using the generic vanilla `query.setParameter` is not advised because it is much slower and error prone than its specialized equivalents. Try one of these:

```
query.setString("searchLang", "deu");
query.setParameter("searchLang", "deu", StringType.INSTANCE);
```

if you are using Hibernate 5.2 or greater than only the latter options is allowed.

Comment: Well I am using the JPA API actually and there is no a setString method or setParameter with such 3 arguments in the javax.persistence.Query

Comment: I see, have you tried the  setParameter(Parameter<T> param, T value) version?

Comment: No.Honestly to say I do not know how to do this?